# Ubuntu Server. Разметка дисков.

Tags: ubuntu

Я совсем новичок. Ставлю Ubuntu Server. Дошел до пункта "Разметка дисков". У меня 3 диска, на одном винда, на других данные. Они будут отформатированы или нет? Если да, то можно ли избежать этого?

Answer (score 2):

1. Там перед подтверждением применения разметки будет табличка с затрагивемыми разделами. Если вам совсем стрёмно и вы не знаете что такое /dev/sda, то отключите физически остальные диски на время установки.
2. http://help.ubuntu.ru/manual/%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0
3. Любопытства ради: А на кой вам сервер?

Comment: Для забавы веб сервер хочу сделать)

Comment: На виртуалку поставь и не парься : )

Answer (score 1):

выберите "ручную разметку диска" (или как-то аналогично по смыслу названо)в этом случае вы сами будете настраивать разделы (какие использовать, какие нет, каие форматировать, какие нет и т.д.)

Answer (score 0):

Почитайте данную статью по установке ОС Linux http://htf.net.ua/install-minimal-debian-squeeze-x64?page=2

Точнее пункт - 7. Разметка дисков